# Apache server-status error 403 Forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403, apache2.4

I’ve the done below following steps to enable Apache server status  in httpd.config configuration.

1. LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
2. Virtual host:

   ```
           <VirtualHost *:20443>
           ServerName  dev-server.com    
           <Location /server-status>
           SetHandler server-status
           Order allow,deny
           Deny from all
           Allow from all
           </Location>        
           </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. ExtendedStatus On

I'm getting error accessing server status screen.

Comment: Please edit the question with the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: This has been done..please look the issue